# Относительный путь для файла

Tags: php, файловые-пути

G:\WebServers\home\check\www\read.js

G:\WebServers\home\popd1\www\show.php

Из одного надо получить другой файл.

../popd1/www/show.php - не работает. Пишет: The requested URL /popd1/www/show.php was not found on this server, как и "../../popd1/www/show.php"

Как я это вижу: "../" ведёт в папку home, и оттуда уже можно же пройти в popd1 и т.д.. Но у PHP другое мнение. Помогите.

Comment: **При чем здесь РНР**, если вам **браузер** человеческим языком пишет, что requested URL /popd1/www/show.php не найден на сервере? И пути надо всегда писать абсолютные. Судя по всему, /show.php - это и есть правильный путь

Comment: `Как я это вижу: "../" ведёт в папку home` оно никуда не ведет, оно поднимает шаг URI на уровень выше исходя из пути текущего файла. но только если есть куда подниматься. если все это пытаетесь запросить из js в браузере, то... для него www/ и есть корень, подъем выше по бэковым директориям просто недоступен клиенту. запрашивайте по домену закрепленному за `pod1/www/`(если играетесь с wamp\xamp на локалке, то `http://popd1/show.php` должно подойти)

Comment: Для локальных адресов домен никогда не пишут. Как раз чтобы не переписывать адреса под каждый сервер.